# Ignore folder with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have the following code in my htaccess, I am trying to get CodeIgniter to ignore the `newdesign` folder.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|newdesign.*|cache.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Using this I can goto `domain.com/newdesign` but not `domain.com/newdesign/anything_else`, it gives a 404

Can anyone shed some light on this?

I'm not great with htaccess!

Just so you know, the `newdesign` folder is an image of the domains CI setup

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|images|newdesign[^/]*|cache[^/]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
RewriteRule ^newdesign(/|$) - [L]
```

before any of the RewriteCond

Comment: There's a space after newdesign which causes a server error. I tried editing it but it's less than 6 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|newdesign|cache.*)
```

What about this, does that work?
I don't think you need a wildcard for `newdesign,

Reference: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the third `RewriteCond`.

This is what I have in my `.htaccess` and everything works fine. I can access images from folders without any problem

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: No sorry that doesn't seem to work either. I tried adding the trailing slash to the URL's and it redirects me from `domain.com/newdesign/anything_else` to `domain.com/anything_else`, basically redirects to the domain.com's version of the page once a trailing slash is added. Which seems very strange.

Comment: Perhaps there's something else in your `.htaccess` that is messing with the whole URL rewrite. Is that really everything inside your `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to just prevent access to that folder you can try and do

```
redirectMatch permanent ^(/newdesign/(.*/)*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/
```

This will redirect anything going to http://www.yourdomain.com/newdesign and anything after that to your specified place.